# Foreign key column allows 0 in SQL Server from bulk insert

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, foreign-keys, sqlbulkcopy

I have a column that checks FK constraints on a column and allows NULL. However, it is allowing 0 as a value even though there is no row for ID of 0 in the primary table.

This insert happens on a bulk insert with .NET. However, if I change the value to a valid number and back to 0 in SQL Server directly then it won't allow it.

So somehow the bulk insert is allowing the 0 to be allowed, is there a reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `BULK INSERT` ignores check and foreign key constraints.  You can turn them on using `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS`.

This is explained in the documentation:

> CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
>
> Specifies that all constraints on the target table or view must be
>   checked during the bulk-import operation. Without the
>   CHECK_CONSTRAINTS option, any CHECK and FOREIGN KEY constraints are
>   ignored, and after the operation, the constraint on the table is
>   marked as not-trusted.

Comment: Yep `SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints` is my setting